# Setting my development and production environment for SharePoint 2013 server

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise, production

I need to set up the development environment and the production environment for SharePoint 2013. I have read the following link on MSDN http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx which mentioned the environment specification for SharePoint 2013 , baring in mind that i am going to install the database and the SP server on the same machine , so i should use the following :-

- 8 to 16 GB or RAM.
- 4 processor cores
- 64-bit edition of Windows Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 (SP1) Standard
- 64-bit edition of Microsoft SQL Server 2012
- 80 GB for system drive
- Visual Studio 2012 Professional

And our size for the application is as follow:-

•   We have two software developers that will be working on developing SharePoint on the development environment.

•   For the production environment we have around 60 internal users & 100 external users.

So i have the following three questions:-

1. Does the link http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx talk about the production environment specification OR the development environment specification?
2. So should i apply the above system specification twice one for the production and the other for the development environment ?
3. or the production environment should have better specification  (than the ones mentioned above( compared to the development environment.?.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. That document describes production environments
2. Do not put SQL on the same box as SharePoint on your live environment. Doing so will kill performance, but is fine for dev environments.
3. You will need to split out SharePoint and SQL onto separate servers. If you plan to deploy Office Web Apps or Search you will definitely need yet another server for each of those platforms.

If your developers are developing farm solutions, they will each need a development environment so as not to interfere with each other's work. If they are developing SharePoint Apps they can do so to separate app webs on the same farm.

Comment: thanks for the reply, so in this case i can have two production servers;First server have 12 GB + 4 processors for the SP , While the Second production Server will have 8 GB + 4 processors for the database server. And for the development environment we can have have both the SP & database on a 8 GB +4 processors single server. Will these high specification be valid?

Comment: Yep that sounds good for the live environment - you might want to add another 4GB of RAM if you can for the dev environment if you will be using service applications such as Reporting Services, PerformancePoint or Search.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i found some articles that mentioned that i need to have three separate servers for production; First one is for the Database, Second server for Application, and the third for the front-end. But in my case i am planning to have only two servers one for the Database and the other for the application and front-end, will it still be valid to have two servers?.

Comment: It'll still be valid, but be prepared to stand up another server to share the load of the applications if things start to get very busy on your web front end/application server.